# Why doesn't this Django filter by 'annotate' variable work?

Tags: django, annotations, django-queryset

I have this queryset in Django:

```
obj = Obj.objects.annotate(duration = F('date_end') - F('date_start')).order_by('duration')
```

The following works perfectly:

```
obj[0].duration

obj.aggregate(Sum('duration'))['duration__sum']
```

However filtering doesn't work in this case even though documentation says that it should:

```
obj = obj.filter( duration__gte = <a_class_datetime.timedelta> )  # doesn't work
obj = obj.filter( duration = 1 )   # doesn't work
```

This is the error I am getting:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

My way to bypass this issue is to loop through the dataset - which is huge. Any tips as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**Python's `timedelta`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) instance while filtering,

```
from datetime import timedelta

obj = obj.filter(duration__gte=timedelta(days=10))
```

---

Apart from that, use [**`ExpressionWrapper`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) to specify the **`output_field`** so that you can avoid unwanted errors.

```
from django.db import models

# for annotation
annotated_queryset = Foo.objects.annotate(
    duration=models.ExpressionWrapper(models.F('date_end') - models.F('date_start'),
                                      output_field=models.DurationField()))

# for filtering
from datetime import timedelta

filtered_queryset = annotated_queryset.filter(duration__gte=timedelta(days=10))
```

Comment: ExpressionWrapper with DurationField in this case works like a charm. Thanks.